# Running specific test class inside a package first in TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I want to run a specific test class before running other tests in the same package using testng xml.

```
test_package
-------------
testclass1
testclass2
testclass3
```

I want testclass3 to run first.

Selenium grid is being used. Currently the longer test runs at last and other nodes are idle making the test duration longer. How can i give first priority to longer test classes.

```
<test name="Tests">
    <packages>
        <package name="tests.*"/>
    </packages>
</test>-->
```

There are multiple classes inside the package but i want selected test class to run ahead of all.

Comment: Best practice is to NOT specify a run order of tests. Tests should be independent of each other and should be able to be run in any order.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the classes in order, you can specify the order in the xml as given below, By default testng, run the classes in order mentioned in xml.

```
<test name="Tests" preserve-order="true">
  <classes>
     <class name="tests.testclass3"/>
     <class name="tests.testclass1"/>
     <class name="tests.testclass2" />
   </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you include

```
 <package name="tests.*"/>
```

Then looks there is no way to say order of classes to execute.

You can try by providing classes with preserve order is testng.xml file or you can create xml file by coding like [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically).